# Does this sequence span $V$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $F$ be a field.
$V$ is a vector space over $F$, consisting of all polynomias of degree less or equal to $3$ with coefficients in $F$. 
Does the sequence $S:\,x,(1-x^2),x^3$ span $V$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Note the dimension of $V$ is 4 and $|S|=3$ so it's impossible for $S$ to span $V$.

Indeed, you cannot generate constant polynomials using this basis.

Comment: And the stadart basis for V is S:1,x,x^2,x^3, right?

Comment: @user2013804 Yes, the standard basis for $V$ would be $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$. But any set of $4$ polynomials with different degree would do -- e.g. $\{5, 3-x, x^2-4x+7, x^2-x^3\}$.